# Storing sensor_msgs::Image from cv_bridge

Tags: opencv, sensor-msgs, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am having some trouble to store the result of *cv_bridge::CvImage::toImageMsg()* as a *sensor_msgs::Image*.

The reason why I want to do this is because the *sensor_msgs::Image* belongs to a custom message I have created which contains some other piece of information.

Is there any way to store a *cv::Mat* in a *sensor_msgs::Image* besides doing it "manually" in a *for* loop?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57452/storing-sensor_msgs::image-from-cv_bridge/) by [Geropan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4375/geropan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The signatures for the method (from [CvImage](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/cv_bridge_redesign/html/classcv__bridge_1_1CvImage.html)) are:

```
void                    toImageMsg (sensor_msgs::Image &ros_image)   const
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr   toImageMsg ()                                const
```

So we use the first option. And note that the image message is passed by reference. So you construct your message, let's say it's `my_msg`, and let's say the image that is a part of it is called `img`. If your `CvImage` object is `my_cv_img` then you would call:

```
my_cv_img.toImageMsg(my_msg.img);
```

And you are done. Note that `toImageMsg` allocates the memory for the image data itself, as can be seen by looking at the code for it: [cv_bridge.cpp](http://mediabox.grasp.upenn.edu/roswiki/doc/api/cv_bridge_redesign/html/cv__bridge_8cpp_source.html)

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2